# Форматирование текста PHP после вывода из БД

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В функцию поступает текст, который взят из БД, допустим такой:

```
text text \n\n\n <advise>text</advise> \n text
```

Как можно с помощью замены `(str replace/preg replace)` сделать так чтобы прямо перед тэгом `<advise>` а так же после тэга `</advise>` не было символов которые переносят строку? Их нужно полностью удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так

```
$text = "text text \n\n\n <advise>text</advise> \n text";
$text = preg_replace('/(\n|\\n)+\s*(?=<advise>)/', '', $text);
echo preg_replace('/(?<=<\/advise>)\s*(\n|\\n)/', '', $text);
```

Comment: неплохой вариант, а как можно использовать эту регулярку на несколько тэгов? к примеру advise|advise1|advise2 и тд?

Comment: $text = preg_replace('/(\n|\\n)+\s*(?=<advise>|<advise3>|<advise2>)/', '', $text); Просто перечисляешь все теги через символ |. Главное не забыть экранировать спецсимволы